# How to register event to Youtube video play progress?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, html5-video

I'm working on a Chrome extension which will display certain messages based on the progress of Youtube video play progress. For example, I'll show message "5 minutes" when the video has played to 5 mins and show message "10 minutes" when the video has played to 10 mins.

One solution is to check the video play progress every 1 second to get the play progress time and decide if we should show any message. Code to get play progress is below:

```
player = document.getElementById("movie_player");
player.getCurrentTime();
```

But I think a better solution would be to register my messages directly to the progress bar of the video player.

To clarify, when I say 5 mins and 10 mins, I mean the exact time on the progress bar. The solution will also need to handle cases like user pause the video or drag the progress bar to play at certain time. And ideally also work when user play the video at 2x, 3x, 4x speed.

Does anyone know if there's a way to register events to player progress bar?

Comment: It looks like there is an element with the class `ytp-time-current` you could get the value from.

Comment: @TroyCarlson  thanks, but I'm able to get the play time fine, I'm just looking for a way to register callback/event to certain times of the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [HTML5 media `timeupdate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate).

> The timeupdate event is fired when the time indicated by the currentTime attribute has been updated.
>
> The event frequency is dependant on the system load, but will be thrown between about 4Hz and 66Hz (assuming the event handlers don't take longer than 250ms to run)

Since YouTube uses `<video>` elements to show video, it should be fairly easy to attach a listener for that event and handle all cases you mention in it's handler.

```js
document
  .querySelector('video')
  .addEventListener('timeupdate', e => {
    console.log(e.target.currentTime)
  })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  left: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<video width="320" height="130" controls>
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: yeah, I found something similar https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp    will pick your answer once I'm done testing :)

Comment: It's not just similar, it's the exact same event.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a `ontimeupdate` callback function which seems to be exactly what I want! I'll test it out.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp